STM32F401RE issue with PWM
Im using a Nucleo board for my shenanigans, I have this PA5 pin on my chip that is connected to the LED2 on the board and can generate a PWM signal but it doesn't and I do not have the clarity to solve it
  RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
  GPIOA->MODER |= ( 0x2UL << GPIO_MODER_MODE5_Pos); //alternate mode
  GPIOA->AFR[0]|= 0x000000010;//alternate function for port A 5
  TIM2->PSC = 840 - 1;     // Set prescaler
  TIM2->ARR = 1000;         // Set auto-reload
  TIM2->CCMR1 |= ( 0x6UL << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos );
  TIM2->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE;
  TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE;
  TIM2->CCER &= ~TIM_CCER_CC1P;
  TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E;
  TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS;
  TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
  TIM2->DIER |= ( TIM_DIER_CC1IE | TIM_DIER_UIE );
  TIM2->SR &= ~( TIM_SR_CC1IF | TIM_SR_UIF );


Here's the code, hope someone can help
I tried swapping around the bits of alternate functions but it didn't work, maybe I just dont know how to fiddle with it

You don't seem to be setting TIM2->CCR1 to set the duty cycle of the output. Also, you need a small delay between enabling the clocks for the peripherals, and accessing their registers.

You didn't enable the timer counter. The timer is off. For testing, set compare value to half of counter reload value (1000/2=500 in your case). If you actually enable the counter later, it could be that PWM actually works, and LED is on for 6/1000 of a second, and you just don't see it with your organic eyes.

@Ilya enabling the counter would be TIM2->CR|=TIM_CR_CEN? And to modify the compare value I would modify the value in the CCR register?
Sorry if I am asking silly questions, I am very new to ARM and register level programming

TIM2->CR|=TIM_CR_CEN - yes. You can't expect timer to do something if the ticking part of the timer is disabled.

Compare value is in the CCR1 register, which contains the value of the counter, at which the state of the timer output will flip. As pointed out by pmacfarlane, you don't set it anywhere. You basically enabled the compare functionality, but you didn't indicate what to compare to. Your timer's counter will tick from 0 to 1000 as it is, but the compare value is not set, it seems.

Thanks ilya, I don't have my STM at me at the moment but the moment I get home tonight Ill modify the code and if it works, I owe you a drink. Thanks to you and pmacfarlane, you guys are bros.

@Ilya we go out for drinks later, this shit is working. all I had to add was Counter enable.  I forgot to put the part of the code where CCR1 changes linearly,
also where do I give you guys some badge that you are badasses

  RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
  GPIOA->MODER |= ( 0x2UL << GPIO_MODER_MODE5_Pos); //alternate mode
  GPIOA->AFR[0]|= 0x000100000;//alternate function for port A 5
  TIM2->PSC = 840 - 1;     // Set prescaler
  TIM2->ARR = 1000;         // Set auto-reload
  TIM2->CCMR1 |= ( 0x6UL << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos );
  TIM2->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE;
  TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE|TIM_CR1_CEN|TIM_CR1_URS;
  TIM2->CCER &= ~TIM_CCER_CC1P;
  TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E;
  TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
  TIM2->DIER |= ( TIM_DIER_CC1IE | TIM_DIER_UIE );
  TIM2->SR &= ~( TIM_SR_CC1IF | TIM_SR_UIF );

This is the final code that worked, Thanks to Ilya and pmacfarlane

You should enable counter only AFTER you did all the configuration. You're lucky it worked at all. TIM_CR1_CEN must be the last line. Otherwise you start the timer counter while timer is only half-configured.

CCR1 configuration is still missing?

Take a look at this repo of mine, it's a basic bare metal timer configuration (with multiple timers and PWM outputs and screenshots of waveforms), I created it specifically as an example. It's mostly similar to what you do, but may clear up some things: https://github.com/ellectroid/STM32F746-CMSIS-Chained-Timers-Demo

It worked anyway, CCR was being modifed later, and CEN was indeed the last line once I modified it, it worked regardless somehow. I am now facing a new problem which I will post about.
